# Child div masked by parent div when scrolled down. Z-index won't apply. Child completely visible when scrolled to top. Z-index is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
<!-- Javascript that shows drop down menu. -->
    $(function () { $(document).scroll(function () { var $nav = $(".navbar-fixed-top"); $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height()); }); }); 

<!-- end  Javascript-->
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Put the code **in the question**...not a comment.

Comment: **Dude** - CODE IN THE QUESTION!

Comment: I don't have enough context to find the problem in your case in particular, but in general I find [*What No One Told You About Z-Index* by Philip Walton](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) very helpful when debugging these sorts of problems.

Comment: The difference in behavior seems to be triggered by the CSS class `scrolled`, you should add the CSS definition of this class to your question. Ideally, since it's about CSS, add the HTML parents in which `navbar-fixed-top` is, and their CSS definitions (you know, the "cascading" part of CSS can be tricky).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own. It was not a z-index problem. It was a problem with the CSS overflow: hidden; in the parent div. No issues in the other browsers except Safari. I changed it to overflow: visible; and the mobile drop down menu showed as designed in Safari as well as the rest.